# Equalise point-distance when optimising points on graph

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Recently I have been learning about optimisation-techniques and built a simple "*gradient-descent brachistochrone solver thingy*" to try out some methods.

One thing currently still hurting the results is the distancing of the points. Obviously, if they are first generated an equal distance on the x-axis apart from each-other, when the resulting graph becomes non-linear the distances between them start to vary quite significantly.

[image: different points spacing example image]

Especially between the first two points there is obviously a massive "hole".

What I would like to as is, if there is any well-established method of spacing these points by their distance from each-other instead of evenly along one axis.
This at first doesn't seem to be too hard a problem; just move them a bit to be at the right place for their heights.
This doesn't really work however, because when changing the "*x-position*" of the points their height must be re-adapted as well, leading to another distance-discrepancy and so on and so forth.

As all algorithms I came up with required an ungodly number of iterations to complete, and I was unable to find the correct keywords to google this problem, this is now asked in form of a post on this forum.

Thanks,
Robbe.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that ou use the parametrization
$$x=r(t-\sin(t)) \qquad \qquad y=r(1-\cos(t))$$ the length os the curve between $0$ and $2\pi$ is given by
$$L=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\text{d}x^2+\text{d}y^2}\,dt=r \sqrt 2\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1-\cos(t)}\,dt =8r$$

So, if you want the points to be at the same distance along the curve, select a first point2 $t_1$ for which the arclength is given by
$$L_{0,t_1}=r \sqrt 2\int_0^{t_1} \sqrt{1-\cos(t)}\,dt=8 r \sin ^2\left(\frac{t_1}{4}\right)$$
$$L_{t_n,t_{n+1}}=r \sqrt 2\int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}} \sqrt{1-\cos(t)}\,dt=4 r \left(\cos \left(\frac{t_n}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{t_{n+1}}{2}\right)\right)$$ Since you want both distances to be equal, knowing $t_n$,
you need to solve for $t_{n+1}$ the equation
$$\cos \left(\frac{t_{n+1}}{2}\right)=2 \cos \left(\frac{t_{n}}{2}\right)-1$$ which is more than simple.

Knowing the $t_n$, just compute  $x_n=r(t_n-\sin(t_n))$.

*Please let me know how it works for you.*

Comment: Thank you very much - that is certainly a good mathematical method for this problem!
However, I went into this with the basic assumption of "the result function [the cycloid for a brachistochrone] is not known" - otherwise there wouldn't really be a point of doing a numerical solution...
Anyway, thank you for the response - certainly very well explained!